# Trying to do onmouseover/onmouseout effect

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to achieve this "circle/layer" effect (https://www.thinglink.com/)

My jQuery skills are terrible :( This is what I've done, so far...

**HTML**

```
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
<div class="container">
    <div class="bubble-container bubble-a">
        <a class="gps_ring" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <div class="dot">dot</div>
        </a>
        <div class="layer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-container bubble-b">
        <a class="gps_ring" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <div class="dot">dot</div>
        </a>
        <div class="layer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble-container bubble-c">
        <a class="gps_ring" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <div class="dot">dot</div>
        </a>
        <div class="layer">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
.container { background-color:black; width:100%; height:400px; }
.layer { background-color:#FFFFFF; display:none; position:absolute; top:-70px; right:20px; width:200px; height:200px; z-index:99999999; overflow:hidden; }
.gps_ring {
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    padding:6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation: 0.6s pulsate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: 0.6s pulsate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
    -ms-animation: 0.6s pulsate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
    -o-animation: 0.6s pulsate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
    animation: 0.6s pulsate infinite alternate ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0.0;
}
.gps_ring div.dot { background-color:transparent; width:100%; height:100%; -webkit-border-radius:30px; outline:none; text-indent:-9999px; }
.gps_ring:hover div.dot { background-color:#ef4036; }

.bubble-container { position: absolute; }

.bubble-a {
    left:150px;
    top:100px;
}
.bubble-b {
    left:250px;
    top:260px;
}
.bubble-c {
    left:350px;
    top:180px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulsate {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.0, 1.0); opacity: 1.0;}
    50% {opacity: 1.0;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1.3, 1.3); opacity: 1.0;}
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".bubble-container .gps_ring").hover(function(){
    $(this).next().show();
    $(this).next().focus();
});

$(".layer").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3d6ogu4/

Sometimes the white layer doesn't hide when mouse out, do you know why?

Also, I would like to set the red dot visible when I am over the white layer too.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(".bubble-container").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.gps_ring').next('.layer').show();
},function(){
    $(this).find('.gps_ring').next('.layer').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/j3d6ogu4/2/)

or you can just use .find()

```
$(".bubble-container").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.layer').show();
},function(){
    $(this).find('.layer').hide();
});
```

Comment: To retain the red dot on hover, you need to add a .hovered class to represent the active link.

    $(this).find('.dot').addClass('hovered') and .removeClass('hovered')

css: .gps_ring:hover div.dot, .gps_ring div.dot.hovered { background-color:#ef4036; }

https://jsfiddle.net/j3d6ogu4/2/

Comment: Thank you @mohamed-yousef !!!! And what about the red circle inside the white one? Is there a way to make the red circle visible while the pointer is over the white layer? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Don't worry! I tested your code in my page and is working! Thank to you two!! Love you all !! :)